# Autolayouts in Android?

Tags: android, ios, autolayout, android-relativelayout, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to create a layout in android with xml editor in android studio. I want to design something similar to what I have in my iOS application.

iOS has Autolayout where we can anchor different view with Parent view, top/bottom layout guides or with some other views. So with Autolayout in iOS I've created 4 buttons horizontally and applied some constraints about leading trailing and height (not width) to the first and last button  and then I've anchored the remaining buttons so that they all have same height and width and will fill all screen sizes(ip 4 to ip XSm) with LTR and RTL layouts support.

Now I want to do the same in Android XML, its possible with linear layouts by setting layout_weight but it will not support LTR and RTL layouts and I'm using some drawables as background that needs to be with LTR and RTL support.

[image]

any help is appreciated.. thanks

Comment: hmm maybe ConstraintLayout knows something you need. It'd be nice to see an image drawn in Paint to see what you want to achieve.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce i want to do something in xml text editor but Constaintlayout is somewhat drag and drop oriented and I don't understand it.

Comment: I would think all you need is a horizontal chain with horizontal chain type `spread`, as LTR/RTL is supported if you use `app:constraintStart_toStartOf` and `app:constraintEnd_toEndOf` instead of right/left, with `app:constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` on all of them.